# Multicollinearity negating $\beta$

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, condition-number

In [Regression coefficients that flip sign after including other predictors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/regression-coefficients-that-flip-sign-after-including-other-predictors), ars's answer states that "Basically, if your variables are positively correlated, then the coefficients will be negatively correlated, which can lead to a wrong sign on one of the coefficients."

This is not intuitive to me, and I was wondering if someone can provide (1) an intuitive explanation (preferably without equations) and (2) a mathematical proof of this effect.

Comment: This is discussed extensively in [related threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20change%20sign%20multicoll*%20score%3a2)--please check them out.

Comment: @whuber I did see several posts on this subject, but I still don't understand high (multi)collinearity leads to a negation in sign of the coefficient. I don't think multicollinearity is guaranteed to call this effect, but it is one possible effect? In other words, there is no guarantee multicollinearity will negate the coefficient?

Comment: Absolutely not!  But contemplating the extreme case where one variable is a positive multiple of the other can be helpful: when the estimated coefficient of the variable increases, the *only* thing the model can do to compensate is to decrease the estimated coefficient of the other variable.

Comment: @whuber This is more so for me than a response to you, but I found this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229052/when-a-and-b-are-positively-related-variables-can-they-have-opposite-effect-on. The top answer shows this geometrically.