# Examples of correlated Xs with opposite effect on Y

Tags: correlation, example

Could someone give me a simple real life example of how two things can be positively correlated, but they have different (opposite) effects on a third variable?

I encountered this scenario and I'm trying to find a simple example to tell my boss that this is not unexpected.

Comment: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/229095/311006).

Comment: also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_(statistics)). Mediation.