# Two variables are correlated but regression is not significant?

Tags: regression, correlation

In simple linear regression analysis, is it possible that "two variables are correlated but regression (main effect) is not significant"?

What does the result mean?

NOTE: My question is different from [X and Y are not correlated, but X is significant predictor of Y in multiple regression. What does it mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33888/x-and-y-are-not-correlated-but-x-is-significant-predictor-of-y-in-multiple-regr) because my question is in simple linear regression analysis.

Comment: You should be more specific when you say correlated. In real data, you always have non-zero correlation. You also need to be more specific when you say that something is not significant. Do you mean to say at a specific threshold (alpha = 0.05)? Depending on how you frame and specify correlation and significance, your answer can change.

Comment: To @MWaz  : r = 0.30 (p = 0.024), beta = 0.07 (95% CI = -0.03, 0.19; p = 0.181)

Comment: @JeffLin r = 0.3 is a very weak correlation and the your confidence interval contains zero. The correlation does not suggest that your regression coefficient is significant, which is supported by your p-value.

Comment: Assuming you have included an intercept, you have performed a multiple regression and so every conclusion in the duplicate applies in your case, too.