# Why important features does not correlated with target variable?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, importance

I'm testing if there is a relation between top important features and correlation between those features and target.

I'm working on the titanic dataset.

I plot the feature importance (using `xgboost`):
[image]

- I checked if there is a relation (correlation) between the top 2 important features (`Fare`, `Age`) and target (`Survived`).
- Moreover I checked the least important feature (`sex`) and target (`Survived`).
- I used 3 different types of correlation methods.

Results:

```
Type: pearson, fare cor: 0.2573065223849625
Type: pearson, Age cor: -0.06980851528714314
Type: pearson, Sex cor: -0.5433513806577555

Type: spearman, fare cor: 0.32373613944480834
Type: spearman, Age cor: -0.03910946205127973
Type: spearman, Sex cor: -0.5433513806577551
   
Type: kendall, fare cor: 0.2662286416742869
Type: kendall, Age cor: -0.03268974393136027
Type: kendall, Sex cor: -0.5433513806577552
```

**As the data shows, it seems that there is no relation at all between important or less important features and the target.**

1. Am I right ?
2. If so, when it will be good idea to use correlation ? (Because we can see in this example that correlated or uncorrelated features doesn't affect the target results)

Comment: although you are talking about xgboost, this question is answered in the context of linear regression here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33888/x-and-y-are-not-correlated-but-x-is-significant-predictor-of-y-in-multiple-regr/34016#34016 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28474/how-can-adding-a-2nd-iv-make-the-1st-iv-significant?
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73869/suppression-effect-in-regression-definition-and-visual-explanation-depiction

Answer (score 5):

1. Not necessarily.  Correlation measures the strength of a linear relationship.  Age appears to have a weak correlation but, the relationship between age and the outcome may not be linear.   See [the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#/media/File:Correlation_examples2.svg) for correlation for some examples in which x and y are related but the correlation is 0.
2. I'm not a big fan of correlation.  Feature importance via correlation seems to miss a lot of important variables.  I demonstrate this in [one of my blog posts](https://dpananos.github.io/posts/2020/12/blog-post-28/).  Correlation feature selection (which would be akin to what you're doing here) fails to result in superior performance over other methods across 2 real datasets and 1 simulated dataset.  I have little confidence in its ability to successfully pick out good predictors (unless those predictors are linearly related to the outcome and not confounded by any other variables).

Comment: kendall correlation dosn't assume linear relationship,does it ? so I assumed (wrongly) that kendall will catch relation between those features and target.

Answer (score 2):

Tree models' measures of feature importance [have](https://explained.ai/rf-importance/) [been](https://blog.hwr-berlin.de/codeandstats/variable-importance-in-random-forests/) [called](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1796903/) [into](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-relook-on-random-forest-and-feature-importance-2467dfab5cca) [question](https://blog.methodsconsultants.com/posts/be-aware-of-bias-in-rf-variable-importance-metrics/) [in general](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-importance-may-be-lying-to-you-3247cafa7ee7).

But also, `xgboost`'s python implementation [`get_score` defaults to "weight"](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.get_score), which measures the *number* of splits a feature makes.  This obviously hurts small-cardinality features like `sex` (which should be highly predictive in `titanic`):  it can only be used to split once per tree; even if it is used for the first split of every tree, if your trees are deep enough its weight-importance will be low.